# Update DOM without reloading the page in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two picklists in DOM, first is populated with initial call to a view (i.e. loading the page). Second picklist's content depends on what user selects in the first one.

Let's say the picklists are:

1. `list_of_events`
2. `list_of_rooms`

Every time the state of the first picklist changes (user selects a different event) I need to update the content of the second picklist (available rooms) without refreshing the page. Is this possible?

My template looks like this:

```
{% block content %}

{% if list_of_events %}
    <form>
        <select>
            {% for event in list_of_events %}
                <option value="name">{{ event.title }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </form>

{% else %}
    <p>No events available now.</p>
{% endif %}
```

For now the second picklist `list_of_rooms` should only be visible if user have selected anything from the `list_of_events` picklist. `first_selection` argument is passed to template if user selects a value in `list_of_events`.

```
{% if first_selection %}
    <form>
        <select>
            {% for room in list_of_rooms %}
                <option value="name">{{ room.id }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </form>
{% endif %}

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

{% endblock %}
```

My `views.py` function looks like this:

```
def events(request):
    list_of_events = Event.objects.all()
    return render(
        request, 
        'web_service/schedule.html', {'list_of_events': list_of_events}
    )
```

Comment: have you considered Ajax?

Comment: You can only repopulate the page without reloading it using Javascript. It can't be done in Python, although you can return the required data in Python. There are plenty of tutorials around on AJAX.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with it, but I do have experience in Angular4 so I'm looking for some similarities. It's possible to simply bind typescript method right to onClick event and DOM will be updated automatically without refreshing the page.

Comment: Typescript is just Javascript with some extra bells and whistles. Fundamentally it's the same scenario.

Comment: If you just need to render different content based on an event, any Javascript framework can do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Django, at least now, there's no direct way to dynamically call `python` method from `html` template without refreshing the page.

To call `python` method and see it's effect in template without refreshing the page you'll need a bit of `JS`, dedicated `url` pattern and a `view`. It’s not as simple as calling instance method, but not as hard as it may seem.

The example below is a demonstration how to respond to a button `click`, send some data to a `view` and return the result to template without refreshing `DOM`.

---

The only way to call python code from template is relate to in the same way as we relate to `url`, this means we have to create new `url pattern`. Then call necessary `view` and return response to template as `JsonResponse`.

**Note**: make sure to import `jquery` at the inside bottom of your `<body>` tag.

First of all we need to create responder which will handle button click and create `AJAX` request to url connected to `view`. `AJAX request` passes `input` as parameter to our url pattern, meaning this parameter will be passed to django `view`. If something returns from our call to `view` then data is being unpacked in `success` closure.

Let’s say our template looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="user-input" autofocus=""><br>
<button type="button" id="sender">Send data</button><br>
<p id="p-text">foo bar</p>
```

Script handling clicks and request looks like this:

```
<script>

$("#sender").click(function () {
    var input = $('#user-input').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'get_response' %}',
        data: {
          'inputValue': input
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          document.getElementById('p-text').innerHTML = data["response"];
        }
      });
    });

</script>
```

New pattern is needed in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^ajax/get_response/$', views.answer_me, name='get_response')
    ...
]
```

**Note:** the `ajax/` part of url and path of url pattern itself has no influence on how this call is handled. It can be anything you want, for example: `^foo/bar/$`.

Last step is adding responding Django `view`. This simple example returns the input with some additional text, but generally this is the place where you can call other python methods and do whatever you want:

```
def answer_me(request):
    user_input = request.GET.get('inputValue')
    data = {'response': f'You typed: {user_input}'}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render all the possible second picklist with a display = none then you can add a javascript like:

```
function show(select_item) {
        if (select_item == "apple") {
            hiddenDiv.style.visibility='visible';
            hiddenDiv.style.display='block';
            Form.fileURL.focus();
        } 
        else{
            hiddenDiv.style.visibility='hidden';
            hiddenDiv.style.display='none';
        }
    }   
</script>  

<form>
<label>Fruit:</label>
    <select name="Fruit" onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
        <option value='pear'>pear</option>
        <option value='apple'>apple</option>
        <option value='grapes'>grapes</option>
    </select>

<div id='hiddenDiv' style="display: none;">
    <label>Are you sure you want to eat the apple?</label>
    <select name="AppleQuestion">
        <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
        <option value='No'>No</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/metrafull2/pen/WEgWLo try here

Comment: this solution has nothing to do with calling python method and is in no way connected to model

Comment: of course it is, I said render all the possible option and according with that show the options, is much easier do that than use angular or ajax, you didn't post your view and your template, so its hard to understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Your absolutely right in scope of dozen options for second picklist, but for every selection in first picklist I have couple hundred sub-selections for second picklist, and I'll need to send values of fisrt and second picklists back to model anyways, so I probably have no other choice than going with ajax-way. But thanks for the idea, I'll probably use it someday.

Comment: well, I thought you didn't have many options, anyway if you liked pls vote up

Comment: anyway post your views and your template, I can help you

Comment: I've added template and calling views method

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to OP (the accepted answer is the closest I can find to what I came up), and this was the top hit to my google search, so I'll share what I came up with.

The main difference is I set the `dataType` to 'html' and just appended the rendered template directly to the element. (if you didnt change the `dataType` you'd end up with exceptions--wouldn't work in the manner I've implemented)

```
//parent_template.html
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "jquery.js" %}"></script>

{% block first %}
<div class="row">
    {% for x in my_list %}
    <button class="some-filter" id="{{x}}"></button>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock first %}

{% block second %}
<div class="row" id="some_id"></div>
{% endblock second %}

<script>
     $(".some-filter").on({
       click: e=> {
           var name = $( e.target )[0].id;
           $.ajax({
             url: '/ajax/info_getter/',
             data: {
               'name': name,
             },
             dataType: 'html',
             success: function (data) {
               if (data) {
                 $("#some_id").html(data);
                 $(".some-filter").removeClass('selected');
                 $( e.target ).addClass('selected');
               }
             }
           });
       }
   })
</script>



// child_template.html
// my big ass template containing lots of image files
{% load static %}
...other stuff

// urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('ajax/info_getter/', views.info_getter, name='info_getter'),
    ...
]



// views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
...
def info_getter(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name', None)
    if name:
        context["name"] = name

    response = render(request, "child_template.html", context=context)
    return response
```

**Note**: I'm not sure if this is considered best practice

**Note**: only tested on Django 2.2 and Python 3.6.x