# Pass value from django view to same template

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to Django. I am trying to create a website with two input textboxes. When the submit button clicked, I need to update the results from django view to the same template without reloading the webpage.

Here is my code so far:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Welcome to Test</H1>

<div class="input-group" >
   Input Text:<br>
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" cols="70"  name="InputText" 
  placeholder="Enter your Input Text here" form="myForm">
 </textarea>
 <span class="input-group-addon"><br></span>
Input TextFSM Template:<br>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="20" cols="70"  name="InputTemplate" 
 placeholder="Enter your template here" form="myForm">
</textarea>
<form  action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<div id="resultid">
<p>Result:</p>
{{result}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
template_name = "index.html"

def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    form = ParserForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    form = ParserForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        inputtext = form['InputText'].value()
        template = form['InputTemplate'].value()
        # Process the data and get the result
        print(result)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'result': result})
```

How to pass the result to index.html from view but the text entered in the textboxes should be persistent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906858/update-dom-without-reloading-the-page-in-django

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to update result in django templates or django views without reloading the page. In addition, once page in rendered you need second request to update that page. You could use **[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** to do fetch data from server without reloading page.

Ajax is *asynchronous javascript extension* which is use to send request with out reloading page. This would help you to do exactly that you want.

You could get more help from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

See following example for an instance.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<body>
<H1>Welcome to Test</H1>

<div class="input-group" >
   Input Text:<br>
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" cols="70"  name="InputText" 
  placeholder="Enter your Input Text here" form="myForm">
 </textarea>
 <span class="input-group-addon"><br></span>
Input TextFSM Template:<br>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="20" cols="70"  name="InputTemplate" 
 placeholder="Enter your template here" form="myForm">
</textarea>
<form id="my-form" action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<div id="resultid">
<p>Result:</p>
{{result}}
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        function processForm( e ){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/url-to-call/',    //replace this with url that you want to hit without reloading the page
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    // manipulate stuff or action
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                     // This is executed when some error occures
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#my-form').submit( processForm );
    })(jQuery);</body>
</html>
```