# Django: How to show the updated information on the page without reloading

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am working in Djnago and I want to update the information without reloading the page. At first, I have used Ajax for post method so that the page should not reload after submitting the form, and it is working properly. Then I used Ajax for get method, and it is working too but to see the new information on the page, I have to refresh the page.

The `view.py` file:

```
def bfs_view(request):
    form = BFSForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = BFSForm()
    try:
        image_url_info = None
        num_states_explored = None
        final_solution = None

        text_file = open("BFS\outputs\maze.txt", "w")
        field_name = 'description'
        input_value = BFS.objects.latest('id')

        field_object = BFS._meta.get_field(field_name)
        field_value = field_object.value_from_object(input_value)


        field_string_value = str(field_value).split("\n")

        text_file.writelines(field_string_value)
        text_file.close()

        m = Maze("BFS\outputs\maze.txt")
        print("Maze:")
        m.print()
        print("Solving...")
        m.solve()
        print("States Explored:", m.num_explored)
        print("Solution:")
        m.print()

        image_url_info = "/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png"
        num_states_explored = m.num_explored
        
        # final_solution = ''.join(m.end_result)
        final_solution = str(''.join(m.end_result))
        print(''.join(m.end_result))

        # BFS.objects.latest('id').delete()
    except:
        print("BFS ERROR: Error in the try session of BFS in view.py")

    context = {
        'form': form, 'image_url': image_url_info, 'states_explored': num_states_explored, 
        'solution': final_solution}

    return render(request, "BFS/bfs.html", context)


def post_bfs_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        bfs_view(request)
        return JsonResponse({"success":True}, status=200)
    return JsonResponse({"success":False}, status=400)


def get_bfs_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax():
        try:
            image_url_info = None
            num_states_explored = None
            final_solution = None

            text_file = open("BFS\outputs\maze.txt", "w")
            field_name = 'description'
            input_value = BFS.objects.latest('id')

            field_object = BFS._meta.get_field(field_name)
            field_value = field_object.value_from_object(input_value)

            field_string_value = str(field_value).split("\n")

            text_file.writelines(field_string_value)
            text_file.close()

            m = Maze("BFS\outputs\maze.txt")
            m.print()
            m.solve()
            print("States Explored:", m.num_explored)
            print("Solution:")
            
            # final_solution = ''.join(m.end_result)
            final_solution = str(''.join(m.end_result))
            print(''.join(m.end_result))
            # bfs_view(request)

            # BFS.objects.latest('id').delete()
            bfs_view(request)
        except:
            print("BFS ERROR: Error in the try session of BFS in view.py")
    return HttpResponse(final_solution)
```

The main `bfs.html` file:

```
 <form id = "contactForm" method='POST' >{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type='submit' value='Search' class="submit-btn poppins"/>
</form>

<div onload="myFunction()">
   <h1>"The value is: " <pre><span id="myText"></span></pre></h1>
</div>
```

The Ajax for `post` operation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#contactForm").submit(function(e){
    // prevent from normal form behaviour

        e.preventDefault();
        // serialize the form data  

        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url :  "{% url 'BFS:contact_submit' %}",
            data : serializedData,
            success : function(response){
            //reset the form after successful submit

                $("#contactForm")[0].reset(); 
            },
            error : function(response){
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
   });
});
</script>
```

The Ajax for `get` operation:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'BFS:get_user_info' %}",
    type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it
    success: function(data) {
        var number = data;
        document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = number;
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Got an error dude');
    }
}); 
</script>
```

The `urls.py` file:

```
app_name = 'BFS'

urlpatterns = [
    path('bfs/', bfs_view),
    # path('ajax/get_user_info', get_bfs_view, name='get_user_info'),
    path('ajax/contact', post_bfs_view, name ='contact_submit'),
    path('ajax/get_user_info', get_bfs_view, name = 'get_user_info'),
]
```

The `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class BFS(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

The `forms.py` file:

```
from django import forms
from .models import BFS

class BFSForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(
                        required=False, 
                        label=False,
                        widget=forms.Textarea(
                                attrs={
                                    'id': 'TA1',
                                    'rows': '10vh',
                                    'cols': '8vw',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Your Map Here',
                                    'class': 'textfield-style',
                                    'style': 'max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;outline: none; border: none; background-color: white; width: 100%; padding: 12px 20px; margin: 8px 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 20px; spellcheck="false";',
                                }
                            )
                        )
    
    class Meta:
        model = BFS
        fields = [
            'description'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BFSForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'})
```

Comment: Hey bro. I'm trying to understand properly. Did you used the `get` method to get the update right but you have to reload the page to see the updated information?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you wrapping what you have used to **get** the update in a function then do the function call after you hit the `success` method after submitting the form...

In your `js` for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#contactForm").submit(function(e){
         // prevent from normal form behaviour

         e.preventDefault();
         // serialize the form data

         var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
             type : 'POST',
             url :  "{% url 'BFS:contact_submit' %}",
             data : serializedData,

             success : function(response){
                 //reset the form after successful submit
                 $("#contactForm")[0].reset();

                 // This will then call for the get request to update the id "myText"
                 live_update();
             },

             error : function(response){
                console.log(response)
             }
        });
    });

    function live_update(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'BFS:get_user_info' %}",
            type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it

            success: function(data) {
                var number = data;
                document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = number;
            },

            error: function() {
                alert('Got an error dude');
            }
       });
    }
 });
```

Also, for the success method within the `live_update` function... You could also use,

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#myText").hide();
    $("#myText").html(data);
    $("#myText").fadeIn(1000);
},
```

That should give it a nice little fade in effect as it updates. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be the time to introduce a frontend framework to your pipeline as it will make life easier to refresh pages upon DOM state changes. I had challenges myself trying to implement similar functionality with Django alone some years back until i introduced React Js.

Here is something that could help you without learning another software altogether:

[Update DOM without reloading the page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906858/update-dom-without-reloading-the-page-in-django)

However, you will notice that the marked answer there still uses Javascript i.e jQuery. So there is no denying the fact that you will need to implement javascript to achieve what you want.

Which is why i mentioned React Js.

Good luck!

Comment: You do have a point about learning React Js for these events. But sometimes it's not necessary to do all of that. All it takes, is to have a little knowledge of jQuery, along with a good logical thinking process and that's all. :-)